# Android: Double-Tap zooms out bitmap image when it's not supposed to...?

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap, ontouch

I'm building an app to generate circles on a bitmap when the user double taps the screen. When the user pinches in or pinches out, the image zooms in and zooms out, and when they use one finger the image can be dragged around.

I wrote code to draw a circle on bitmap when the user double-taps, and it works well EXCEPT that the image gets zoomed WAY OUT after it draws the circle...is something wrong with the gesturedetector class I wrote (the class is at the bottom of the following code:)

```
public class ZoomInZoomOut extends ImageView {
private static final String TAG = "ZoomableImageView";

private Bitmap imgBitmap = null;

private int containerWidth;
private int containerHeight;

Paint background;

//Matrices will be used to move and zoom image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

PointF start = new PointF();

float currentScale;
float curX;
float curY;

//We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

//For animating stuff
float targetX;
float targetY;
float targetScale;
float targetScaleX;
float targetScaleY;
float scaleChange;
float targetRatio;
float transitionalRatio;

float easing = 0.2f;
boolean isAnimating = false;

float scaleDampingFactor = 0.5f;

//For pinch and zoom
float oldDist = 1f;
PointF mid = new PointF();

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

float minScale;
float maxScale = 8.0f;

float wpRadius = 25.0f;
float wpInnerRadius = 20.0f;

float screenDensity;
Context context;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public static final int DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE = 0;
public static final int DEFAULT_SCALE_ORIGINAL = 1;

private int defaultScale;

public int getDefaultScale() {
    return defaultScale;
}

public void setDefaultScale(int defaultScale) {
    this.defaultScale = defaultScale;
}

public ZoomInZoomOut(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    screenDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    initPaints();
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    this.context=context;
}

public ZoomInZoomOut(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    screenDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    initPaints();
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

    defaultScale = ZoomInZoomOut.DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE;
}

private void initPaints() {
    background = new Paint();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);

    //Reset the width and height. Will draw bitmap and change
    containerWidth = width;
    containerHeight = height;

    if(imgBitmap != null) {
        int imgHeight = imgBitmap.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = imgBitmap.getWidth();

        float scale;
        int initX = 0;
        int initY = 0;

        if(defaultScale == ZoomInZoomOut.DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE) {
            if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {
                scale = (float)containerWidth / imgWidth;
                float newHeight = imgHeight * scale;
                initY = (containerHeight - (int)newHeight)/2;

                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
            }
            else {
                scale = (float)containerHeight / imgHeight;
                float newWidth = imgWidth * scale;
                initX = (containerWidth - (int)newWidth)/2;

                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
            }

            curX = initX;
            curY = initY;

            currentScale = scale;
            minScale = scale;
        }
        else {
            if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {
                initY = (containerHeight - (int)imgHeight)/2;
                matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
            }
            else {
                initX = (containerWidth - (int)imgWidth)/2;
                matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
            }

            curX = initX;
            curY = initY;

            currentScale = 1.0f;
            minScale = 1.0f;
        }


        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(imgBitmap != null && canvas != null)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(imgBitmap, matrix, background);
    }
}

//Checks and sets the target image x and y co-ordinates if out of bounds
private void checkImageConstraints() {
    if(imgBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    float[] mvals = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(mvals);

    currentScale = mvals[0];

    if(currentScale < minScale) {
        float deltaScale = minScale / currentScale;
        float px = containerWidth/2;
        float py = containerHeight/2;
        matrix.postScale(deltaScale, deltaScale, px, py);
        invalidate();
    }

    matrix.getValues(mvals);
    currentScale = mvals[0];
    curX = mvals[2];
    curY = mvals[5];

    int rangeLimitX = containerWidth - (int)(imgBitmap.getWidth() * currentScale);
    int rangeLimitY = containerHeight - (int)(imgBitmap.getHeight() * currentScale);


    boolean toMoveX = false;
    boolean toMoveY = false;

    if(rangeLimitX < 0) {
        if(curX > 0) {
            targetX = 0;
            toMoveX = true;
        }
        else if(curX < rangeLimitX) {
            targetX = rangeLimitX;
            toMoveX = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        targetX = rangeLimitX / 2;
        toMoveX = true;
    }

    if(rangeLimitY < 0) {
        if(curY > 0) {
            targetY = 0;
            toMoveY = true;
        }
        else if(curY < rangeLimitY) {
            targetY = rangeLimitY;
            toMoveY = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        targetY = rangeLimitY / 2;
        toMoveY = true;
    }

    if(toMoveX == true || toMoveY == true) {
        if(toMoveY == false) {
            targetY = curY;
        }
        if(toMoveX == false) {
            targetX = curX;
        }

        //Disable touch event actions
        isAnimating = true;
        //Initialize timer
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImagePositionTask);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateImagePositionTask, 100);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float oldX = 0, newX = 0, sens = 5;
    if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }

    if(isAnimating == true) {
        return true;
    }

    //Handle touch events here
    float[] mvals = new float[9];
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(isAnimating == false) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                oldX = event.getX();
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if(oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            newX = event.getX();
            if (Math.abs(oldX - newX) < sens) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            oldX = 0;
            newX = 0;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;

            matrix.getValues(mvals);
            curX = mvals[2];
            curY = mvals[5];
            currentScale = mvals[0];

            if(isAnimating == false) {
                checkImageConstraints();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(mode == DRAG && isAnimating == false) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float diffX = event.getX() - start.x;
                float diffY = event.getY() - start.y;

                matrix.postTranslate(diffX, diffY);

                matrix.getValues(mvals);
                curX = mvals[2];
                curY = mvals[5];
                currentScale = mvals[0];
            }
            else if(mode == ZOOM && isAnimating == false) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if(newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.getValues(mvals);
                    currentScale = mvals[0];

                    if(currentScale * scale <= minScale) {
                        matrix.postScale(minScale/currentScale, minScale/currentScale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    else if(currentScale * scale >= maxScale) {
                        matrix.postScale(maxScale/currentScale, maxScale/currentScale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    else {
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }


                    matrix.getValues(mvals);
                    curX = mvals[2];
                    curY = mvals[5];
                    currentScale = mvals[0];
                }
            }

            break;
    }

    //Calculate the transformations and then invalidate
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x/2, y/2);
}

public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    if(b != null) {
        imgBitmap = b;

        containerWidth = getWidth();
        containerHeight = getHeight();

        int imgHeight = imgBitmap.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = imgBitmap.getWidth();

        float scale;
        int initX = 0;
        int initY = 0;

        matrix.reset();

        if(defaultScale == ZoomInZoomOut.DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE) {
            if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {
                scale = (float)containerWidth / imgWidth;
                float newHeight = imgHeight * scale;
                initY = (containerHeight - (int)newHeight)/2;

                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
            }
            else {
                scale = (float)containerHeight / imgHeight;
                float newWidth = imgWidth * scale;
                initX = (containerWidth - (int)newWidth)/2;

                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
            }

            curX = initX;
            curY = initY;

            currentScale = scale;
            minScale = scale;
        }
        else {
            if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {
                initX = 0;
                if(imgHeight > containerHeight) {
                    initY = 0;
                }
                else {
                    initY = (containerHeight - (int)imgHeight)/2;
                }

                matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
            }
            else {
                initX = (containerWidth - (int)imgWidth)/2;
                if(imgHeight > containerHeight) {
                    initY = 0;
                }
                else {
                    initY = (containerHeight - (int)imgHeight)/2;
                }
                matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
            }

            curX = initX;
            curY = initY;

            currentScale = 1.0f;
            minScale = 1.0f;
        }

        invalidate();
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "bitmap is null");
    }
}

public Bitmap getPhotoBitmap() {
    return imgBitmap;
}


private Runnable mUpdateImagePositionTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        float[] mvals;

        if(Math.abs(targetX - curX) < 5 && Math.abs(targetY - curY) < 5) {
            isAnimating = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImagePositionTask);

            mvals = new float[9];
            matrix.getValues(mvals);

            currentScale = mvals[0];
            curX = mvals[2];
            curY = mvals[5];

            //Set the image parameters and invalidate display
            float diffX = (targetX - curX);
            float diffY = (targetY - curY);

            matrix.postTranslate(diffX, diffY);
        }
        else {
            isAnimating = true;
            mvals = new float[9];
            matrix.getValues(mvals);

            currentScale = mvals[0];
            curX = mvals[2];
            curY = mvals[5];

            //Set the image parameters and invalidate display
            float diffX = (targetX - curX) * 0.3f;
            float diffY = (targetY - curY) * 0.3f;

            matrix.postTranslate(diffX, diffY);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 25);
        }

        invalidate();
    }
};

private Runnable mUpdateImageScale = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        float transitionalRatio = targetScale / currentScale;
        float dx;
        if(Math.abs(transitionalRatio - 1) > 0.05) {
            isAnimating = true;
            if(targetScale > currentScale) {
                dx = transitionalRatio - 1;
                scaleChange = 1 + dx * 0.2f;

                currentScale *= scaleChange;

                if(currentScale > targetScale) {
                    currentScale = currentScale / scaleChange;
                    scaleChange = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                dx = 1 - transitionalRatio;
                scaleChange = 1 - dx * 0.5f;
                currentScale *= scaleChange;

                if(currentScale < targetScale) {
                    currentScale = currentScale / scaleChange;
                    scaleChange = 1;
                }
            }


            if(scaleChange != 1) {
                matrix.postScale(scaleChange, scaleChange, targetScaleX, targetScaleY);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateImageScale, 15);
                invalidate();
            }
            else {
                isAnimating = false;
                scaleChange = 1;
                matrix.postScale(targetScale/currentScale, targetScale/currentScale, targetScaleX, targetScaleY);
                currentScale = targetScale;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImageScale);
                invalidate();
                checkImageConstraints();
            }
        }
        else {
            isAnimating = false;
            scaleChange = 1;
            matrix.postScale(targetScale/currentScale, targetScale/currentScale, targetScaleX, targetScaleY);
            currentScale = targetScale;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImageScale);
            invalidate();
            checkImageConstraints();
        }
    }
};

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append("]");
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {



    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {


        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap.getWidth(),
               imgBitmap.getHeight(),
                imgBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(imgBitmap, matrix, null);
        canvas.drawCircle((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY(),
                100, p);

        setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the image bitmap.  setImageBitmap call matrix.reset.  So when you do that, you're losing your zoom factor.  You need to fiddle with your code/architecture to prevent that call.

Comment: I'm not sure what to change though...do you have any ideas?

Comment: First thing to try is just setting the imgBitmap variable and invalidating, rather than calling setImageBitmap.  If that isn't working right, then you need to create a version of setImageBitmap that removes the setting of scale factor but still allows you to set the image.  But you can't clear that matrix, once you do you lose your current scale factor and reset to 1

Comment: For the first thing you said - I'm not sure what you mean by setting the imgBitmap variable and then invalidating. I thought I set the image bitmap with setImageBitmap? I tried replacing the setImageBitmap with just a plain invalidate(); statement but that doesn't draw the circle...

Comment: I meant try setting the variable directly, rather than calling the function which causes a whole lot of other code to be executed.